# Event stream in Microsoft Fabric

Tags: event-stream, spark-notebook, microsoft-fabric

I'm currently using Microsoft Fabric to discover the tool and prepare a presentation. For this presentation I'm using an Event Stream where my data source is a test dataset (i.e. Yellow Taxi). In destination I have a Delta table and a KQL database. From this table I want to perform complex transformations that are not possible in the Event Stream, in order to link my new created delta table with other dimension tables already present in my onelake. How can I do this?

I thought of creating a notebook that would create a new table, insert the data from the delta table loaded by event stream into this new table and then truncate the table from Event Stream, but it's impossible to truncate the delta table. So i'm quite lost right now.
Any advice will be welcome.